# How can I correctly add an if statement inside another?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, html

I'm trying to make that a "Quick view" button appears **only** to registered users.

I'm using WordPress and Woocommerce.

The code I guess I need to modify is this one:

```
<?php 
    if (etheme_get_option('quick_view')): ?>
    <span class="show-quickly" data-prodid="<?php echo $post->ID;?>" style="font-size:11px; cursor: pointer;"><?php _e('Quick View', ETHEME_DOMAIN) ?></span>       
<?php endif ?>
```

I'm guessing I need to add:

```
if(is_user_logged_in())
```

But I must admit I'm not experienced enough on PHP. How can I implement it?

Comment: Would this work: `if(etheme_get_option('quick_view') && is_user_logged_in()):`? I have no experience with Wordpress and/or Woocommerce

Comment: Not sure how inexperienced with PHP you are, but just in case, the `&&` operator in the answer and the other comment means that both conditions in the if statement must be met for the code to be executed. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: Yeah, i understand the logic behind &&. But I don't know PHP syntax yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do as follows in order to check both conditions:

```
<?php 
    if (etheme_get_option('quick_view') && is_user_logged_in()): ?>
    <span class="show-quickly" data-prodid="<?php echo $post->ID;?>" style="font-size:11px; cursor: pointer;"><?php _e('Quick View', ETHEME_DOMAIN) ?></span>       
<?php endif ?>
```